# Adding single quotes to column in data frame

Tags: r

I have a df with multiple columns that have many rows. I want to take one column and add single quotes around the values and a comma afterwards.

```
Column x
111111
222222
333333
444444
```

What I wanted it to look like:

```
Column x
'111111',
'222222',
'333333',
'444444',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your column is `df$x` you would do:

```
df$x <- paste0("'", df$x, "',")
```

Comment: It's okay to edit your post but somebody else have already provided the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

For a single quote, `sQuote` can be used.

```
df1[,1] <- sQuote(df1[,1])
```

Or we can use `sprintf` to include the `'` and the `,` afterwards

```
df1[,1] <- sprintf("'%d',", df1[,1])
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use

`df$x <- paste0("'", df$x, "'", ",")`

This should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
# data to build the df
Column x
a <- "111111"
b <- "222222"
c <- "333333"

# assemble the df
df <- data.frame(rbind(a,b,c))
names(df) <- "Column.X"

df$Column.X <- paste("'",df$Column.X,"',")
```